# How to delete an event in fullcalendar ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I am trying to delete an event when clicked with the pop up modal delete button. Could someone help me out please? I have the delete method in the controller that I am trying to use when an event has been selected. I want to be able to click on the event and then delete the event once the delete button has been clicked.

Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEventsRepo eventsRepo;
    private readonly EventsContext db;
    

    public HomeController(IEventsRepo _eventsRepo, EventsContext _db)
    {
        eventsRepo = _eventsRepo;
        db = _db;
    }


   
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetEvents()
    {
        var events = db.Event.Select(e => new
        {
            id = e.ID,
            title = e.Title,
            start = e.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            end = e.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        }).ToList();
        return new JsonResult(events);
        
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEvent(Events model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newEvent = new Events
            {
                ID = model.ID,
                Title = model.Title,
                Start = model.Start,
                End = model.End
            };
            await eventsRepo.CreateAsync(newEvent);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View();



    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DeleteEvent(int id)
    {
        var deleteEvent = eventsRepo.GetById(id);
        if (deleteEvent == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var model = new Events()
        {
            ID = deleteEvent.ID,
            Title = deleteEvent.Title,
            Start = deleteEvent.Start,
            End = deleteEvent.End
        };
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEvent(Events model)
    {
        await eventsRepo.Delete(model.ID);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Index:

```
  @model DataAccess.Models.Events
  @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
  }

  <div class="modal fade" id="eventModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h5>

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><b>Start:</b> <span id="eventStart"></span></p>
            <p><b>End:</b> <span id="eventEnd"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">
                <i class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit
            </button>
            
                <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> Delete
                </button>
            

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <form method="post" asp-action="CreateEvent" id="BookingForm">
<div class="modal fade" id="saveModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"> New Booking </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name..." />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Start"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Start" id="inputStart" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Start date and time..." />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Start" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="End"></label>
                    <input asp-for="End" id="inputEnd" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter End date and time..." />
                    <span asp-validation-for="End" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Save </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> Cancel </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <script>


var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    navLinks: true,
    eventColor: 'green',
    eventClick: function (info) {
        selectedEvent = info.event;
        console.log(selectedEvent);
        $('#modalTitle').text(info.event.title);
        $('#eventStart').text(info.event.start);
        $('#eventEnd').text(info.event.end);
        $('#eventModal').modal();
    },
    events: '@Url.Action("getevents", "home")',
    Selectable: true,
    dateClick: function () {
        $('#saveModal').modal();

    }
})


calendar.render();




</script>
```

Comment: Your request is a little unclear, you didn't say exactly where you're stuck. But from a glance at the code I can see that your event modal doesn't get given the ID of the event, so you've no way of sending that ID to the server to initiate the delete. You could get the ID from fullCalendar and put it in a hidden field or something. And of course you don't have any code to actually send anything to the server for deletion - either a form or some code to trigger an AJAX request. So please clarify exactly where your difficulty lies, then we can give more specific help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, as @ADyson mentioned, you can try to get and store the `id` of specific event in a hidden field, so that you can make a AJAX request to pass that event id to action method, like below.

*Use a hidden filed to store event id*

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="eventId" value="" />
    <p><b>Start:</b> <span id="eventStart"></span></p>
    <p><b>End:</b> <span id="eventEnd"></span></p>
</div>
```

*Get and store event id in hidden filed*

```
eventClick: function (info) {
    selectedEvent = info.event;
    console.log(selectedEvent);
    $('#eventId').val(info.event.id);
    $('#modalTitle').text(info.event.title);
    $('#eventStart').text(info.event.start);
    $('#eventEnd').text(info.event.end);
    $('#eventModal').modal();
}
```

*Delete button and `delEvenet()` function*

```
<button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;" onclick="delEvenet();">
    <i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> Delete
</button>
```

Code of *`delEvenet()` function*

```
function delEvenet() {
    var event_id = $('#eventId').val();
    console.log(event_id);

    $.get('@Url.Action("DeleteEvent", "home")?id=' + event_id, function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

*Action method*

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DeleteEvent(int id)
{
    //...
    //your code logic here
    
    return Ok("deleted");
}
```

Test Result

[image]